# A new idea on unifying sound and light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, acoustics

Got a new idea regarding the unification of light wave and sound wave into a single entity, may be probably a wave. Is it possible to proceed in that manner,and has it been done previously,like i have an idea of projecting. The light wave and sound wave and synchronizing their speeds, and let them meet at a point, forming interference, or merging at a point will it create a new wave.

If it have been implemented in past can I know the way of unification of sound and light and its applications?

Comment: given the amount of information you have provided, what sort of answer are you expecting to receive?

Comment: This is not a site to promote your own theories, as explained in the FAQ.

Comment: Dear Pavan I see from your profile that you are young enough not to have covered too much in your physics studies. Maybe it would be a good idea to take a few courses of physics at college level to get a solid grounding in all aspects of physics. Then you would become aware of the impossibility of your suggestions without needing external input.

Comment: @lurscher sir i am having an idea of unifying light wave and sound wave i want to know whether it is possible or not

Comment: @anna v thank you very much sir now i am doing my b.tech i just got an idea and i want to implement this one with someone who is showing interest in this area. If anybody are interested i want to give it for them i am a mechanical student i just want to know whether it is possible or not

Comment: the closest thing to what I understand your question to ask for might be [Sonoluminescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence)

Answer (score 4):

Sound and light are inherently different.

Sound is produced in a form similar to that of a 1 dimensional wave: air is compressed and then stretched.

Light is of an inherently different nature: electricity and magnetism interact in a fashion that propagates their energy through space in the the form of light.

Light and sound do not interfere with one another. Why? A molecule of gas (that is an element of a sound wave) may absorb photons of certain wavelengths. The atom has certain electromagnetic properties that allow it to interact with and absorb light. Sound (the mere changes in air density) lacks the ability to interact with the electromagnetic essence of light waves. Apples and Oranges.

Comment: light and sound do not interact? pish. http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v74/i6/e063811 (literally the first paper I found -- I have no idea how active this particular idea is, but cavity systems are very hot right now)

Comment: Would be nice If I could read it without paying $25

Comment: you're in luck! arxiv version: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0609200 (protip -- if you want to read a theoretical physics paper published after 1994, just google the title: if there isn't an arxiv version, then the paper may as well not exist at all...)

Comment: actually i am not doing any professional course in physics i am doing graduation in mechanical department i just got an idea i want a person who can make this idea work out i can get raw ideas but converting them into technical ones feels difficult for me because my subject in mechanical not physics i don't want to waste this idea by keeping with myself i want technical help